# recursively create tuples from lists

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of lists such as:
      `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`
I'm trying to create tuples of the form `(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(2,4),(2,5),(4,7),(4,8),...`

In other words, items in the first list should be tuples with items in subsequent lists, items in the second list, tuples with items from its subsequent lists and so on, until we get to the last list.

I'm a bit unsure of how a list comprehension in python here would work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tuple order doesn't matter for this case? i.e., it's sufficient to generate (4,7), you don't also have to generate (7,4)?

Comment: tuple order does matter. right now, i'm fiddling with
`print [(y,z) for z in lists for y in z  for x in y]` but in the case above, we only want (4,7) and not (7,4)

Comment: More formally, is it "for a list defined by [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n], for each element a_k_j of a_k, generate a tuple  (a_k_j,a_i_h) for all h in each list a_i where i > k and i <= n"? In other words, for each list, generate a tuple of each element in that list combined with each element in all the following lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of list (lol), then, pop first item from list of list and make cartesian product with concatenate remaining lists:

```
import itertools
lol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
result = list()
while lol:
    l=lol.pop(0)
    o=itertools.chain(*lol)
    result += itertools.product( l,o )
```

result
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9)]

Answer (score 2):

A solution using just a big list comprehension would be:

> **WARNING:** only for list comprehension lovers

```
sum([[(elem,e) for e in sum(my_lists[i+1:], [])] for i,my_list in enumerate(my_lists[:-1]) for j,elem in enumerate(my_list)], [])
```

Result:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: can you please explain how sum([],[]) above works? Couldn't find any documentation for it. thanks

Comment: the second param in `sum` is like a initial value. Then, it starts adding (to that initial value) all the elements from the first param using `+=`. That's why `sum([[1,2],[3]],[6])` returns `[6,1,2,3]` (`[6]+[1,2]+[3]`)

Answer (score 1):

Without destroying the original list:

```
from itertools import chain, product
lol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list(chain(*(product(item, chain(*lol[index+1:])) for index, item in enumerate(lol))))
```

Comment: neat. i had to do a deepcopy before :-)

Answer (score 0):

The basic mechanism you want is called `zip` in functional programming. From the [Haskell Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#g:19):

> `zip` takes two lists and returns a list of corresponding pairs. If one input list is short, excess elements of the longer list are discarded.

There's a [built-in zip() function in Python that does essentially the same thing](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: ok, i'll see if i can get that to work for more than two lists.

Comment: It already does. It takes as many iterables as you need, evaluating them from left to right.

Comment: -1 This doesn't do what the OP wants. OP wants every element of the first sublist to be paired with each element of the remaining sublists, for example.